# OpenGL with VBA

Tags: opengl

I have a lot of data that I generate from an Excel spreadsheet and would like to render them graphically using OpenGL by launching it from within a VBA module.
 Here, I mean Visual Basic for **APPLICATIONS**, (not .NET). Could somebody give me a pointer on how to get started.

I've written lots of C++ code with OpenGL, but I'd like to know how to get that first foot in the door with regards to including OpenGL in a VBA environment. I'm running Windows 7. Thanks

Comment: Since this is a VBA-specific question, and there aren't a lot of VBA-using graphics researchers, I doubt you'll get good answers here; you might do better on [so].

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find what I needed with some digging anyway, but I'll be sure to post all future followup questions there.

Comment: If you feel the answer you discovered for yourself might be relevant to others working with computer graphics in future, you could add a self answer to this question.

Comment: Will do. Once I get off this train! :-)

Answer (score 3):

As promised but with apologies for the tardiness, here's a GREAT repository of detailed information for using OpenGL with VBA:

[Découvrez la 3D OpenGL 1.1 en VB6/VBA | arkham46.developpez.com](http://arkham46.developpez.com/articles/office/vbaopengl/?page=page_1)

It's in French, but translates beautifully. I wa able to get OpenGL up and running in less than 15 mins using this SUPERB tutorial.